# GCP Storage usage from Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

Since the node v10 changes to Cloud Functions, one thing that we've come to accept is a default storage bundle within our GCP of which accrues a cost of ~$0.03 a month. It is believed to be Docker cache files that store the Cloud Functions, Node Modules, and Hosting Revisions.

But on an almost empty project, how can you have 535MB in storage when the source is only 83MB total?

- no hosting
- 2 cloud functions

What are the contents of the Files? is it overhead for the revision history? is there any reasonable way to minimize it? I get asked these questions many times and I do not have an answer that I feel comfortable with.

Comment: I'd probably ask Firebase Support directly and then self answer the question.

Comment: Deploying something as simple as a Cloud Function requires additional runtime resources. Resources for Google Cloud services are usually stored in your account. In the Google Cloud Console, go to "Container Registry". In the left column click on "Images". You see a list of objects related to Cloud Run, App Engine, Cloud Functions, etc. Next, go to Cloud Storage. Look for bucket names like "gcf-sources ...", "artifacts ...", "staging ..." "us.artifacts ...", etc. Then there is "Artifact Registry" ...

Comment: I know Frank and Doug use StackOverflow and I know I would get a more knowledgable answer from a firebaser directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the entire container image, so I imagine it contains lot of things that you don't deploy yourself - like the operating system the code runs on, and the runtime of the language you use (Node.js if you're using Firebase to deploy).